# Importing a python class implementing cv2 without running the video frame on loading

Tags: python, import, camera

am importing a class having cv2 implementation from another file( am using cv2 to open my webcam camera). I have a button that I must click to call the imported class but, it doesn't open to display the button but opens the live feed when loading the file. How can I handle this? below is my importation:

```
from monitor import MyView #monitor file has cv2 implementation
class MonitorVid(MyView, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MonitorVid, self).__init__()
        # print("Inside the class ")
```

Comment: I don't see any involvement of OpenCV. please explain or untag.

Comment: I corrected the tag to `opencv` because you're supposed to use opencv+python tags, not the cv2 tag. another reason: it's got a lot more traffic, hence more people that will see your question... but suit yourself